# Why am I getting file sharing exceptions when using ReadWriteLock in C#?

Tags: c#, file, logging, locking

Here is the output from my latest run, where I'm indexing 10 columns of a database table in parallel.  The code for the writing to the log file is below.

```
INFO: Status Indexing column Master_State as index I5
INFO: Status Indexing column Master_current0 as index I4
INFO: Status Indexing column Master_qlevel as index I3
INFO: Status Indexing column Master_received_Day as index I1
Got sharing exception with lock!
INFO: Status Indexing column Master_customer as index I7
Waiting on file
INFO: Status Indexing column Master_received_Year as index I8
INFO: Status Indexing column Master_received_Month as index I9
Waiting on file
INFO: Status Indexing column seq_no as index I10
```

Here is the code that writes the message 'Got sharing exception with lock!'

```
private static void WriteToPath(object msg, string logPath)
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        { // These first two lines are to handle different users and/or
          // applications that log to the same log file.
          // If the File.Open fails because the file is in use, Exception
          // then wait and try again.
          //
            FileStream writer = File.Open(logPath, FileMode.Append);
            writer.Close();

            locker.AcquireWriterLock(writerTimeouts);
            try
            {
                Interlocked.Increment(ref writes);
                try
                {
                    using (var logWriter = File.AppendText(logPath))
                    {
                        logWriter.WriteLine((string)msg);
                    }
                    break; // break out of the while loop as we're done.
                }
                catch
                { // Here I write out the fact that I got an exception
                  // but not the long details about file sharing exception.
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Got sharing exception with lock!");
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (locker.IsWriterLockHeld)
                    locker.ReleaseWriterLock();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref writerTimeouts);
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Waiting on file");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
}
```

This WriteToPath is called as shown here:

```
public static void Log(string dir, string pgm, string errorLevel, string msgType, string details)
{
    string line = null;
    if (details != null)
    {
        line = FormatLogMessage(pgm, errorLevel, msgType, details);
    }
    else
    {
        line = FormatLogMessage(pgm, "INFO", "End", BuildInfo.ApplicationName);
    }
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(WriteWithLock, line);
}

private static void WriteWithLock(object msg)
{
    string logPath = _cfg.getLogDirectory() + GetLogFileName();
    WriteToPath(msg, logPath);
}
```

This is a part of a series of applications that are run in parallel using the

```
  ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
            info.FileName = batchFile;
            info.Arguments = argList;
            Process.Start(info);
```

Thus, each application runs independently.  As such, they do not have a shared or common lock, but one for each application.  Those applications usually run about 10 threads all doing similar work, such as indexing columns of a database, or inserting rows from 10 different files into a database, etc.  For those, the lock mechanism above should work.  But, I get waiting on file, and occasionally that 'sharing exception'.  It works, for the parallel threads and I don't loose any data, but why is it occurring?  Also, will this work for the separate applications?

It seems like Windows 10 should have something like a 
    System.Logging.LogToFile(path, message) that anyone could call and the system would manage any conflicts.  I can't find anything like this, but it sure would be nice!

Assistance on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I know its not an answer, but I do have a nice little logger that ive been using the last few years, if you would like the code, it will get you the LogToFile() that your looking for I think

Comment: If you think it would handle the problem I describe, I'd be interested in seeing it.

Comment: One last shot here, since I don't have any code since b/c i have not run into this issue before, I searched for an implementation that I thought would work, and came across this - Is this kind of what you are looking for? [file-lock](https://github.com/markedup-mobi/file-lock)

Comment: I mean, me being more of a network engr, I would personally like to do this by creating a listening socket on the computer where the log is stored, udp to that from the remote computers, and have the logging computer do the locking, but thats just me, I dont know your networks topology,  and I'm probably over complicating this to make it more in tune with what im familiar with. Well, I tried i guess.

Comment: I think that may be the answer. Just thought maybe someone would have a simple idea. Like, use the XXX log function.

Comment: So these are different OS processes writing to the same file? These processes do not share the ReaderWriterLock instance therefore are not coordinated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trimmed down version of what I use, the Mutex should do what you're looking for, at least this has worked for me without issue:

```
public sealed class GlobalLogger : IDisposable
{
    private static GlobalLogger Logger;
    private readonly Mutex _lock;
    private string _activityLogPath;
    private const string ActivityLogFileName =  @"activity.log";

    private GlobalLogger()
    {
        _lock = new Mutex(false, ActivityLogFileName);          
    }

    /// <summary> Finds the root path of the MSD, sets up log file. </summary>
    /// <returns>Drive info, or null if not found</returns>
    public static void Init()
    {
        if (null == Logger)
        {
            Logger = new GlobalLogger();
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_activityLogPath))
        {
            Logger._activityLogPath = ActivityLogFileName;
        }
    }

    //
    // Debug 
    //
    public static void DebugWriteLineInfo(object sender, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        DebugWriteMessage(sender, "I", true, format, args);
    }

    public static void DebugWriteLineWarning(object sender, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        DebugWriteMessage(sender, "W", true, format, args);
    }

    public static void DebugWriteLineError(object sender, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        DebugWriteMessage(sender, "E", true, format, args);
    }

    private static void DebugWriteMessage(object sender, string severity, bool writeLine, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        if (writeLine)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(format);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Write(format);
        }     
    }

    //
    // Logging
    //
    private static void Log(string logType, string severity, object sender, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        Init();

        if (Logger._lock.WaitOne(250))
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Logger._activityLogPath, true))
                {
                    if (logType != "RAW")
                    {
                        sw.Write("{0} {1} {2} ",
                            DateTime.Now,
                            logType,
                            severity);
                    }

                    sw.WriteLine(format, args);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Logger._lock.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void LogActivityInformation(object sender, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        Log("ACT", "I", sender, format, args);  
    }

    public static void LogActivityWarning(object sender, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        Log("ACT", "W", sender, format, args);  
    }

    public static void LogActivityError(object sender, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        Log("ACT", "E", sender, format, args);  
    }
    public static void LogApplicationInformation(object sender, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        Log("APP", "I", sender, format, args);  
    }

    public static void LogApplicationWarning(object sender, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        Log("APP", "W", sender, format, args);  
    }

    public static void LogApplicationError(object sender, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        Log("APP", "E", sender, format, args);  
    }

    public static void LogSystemInformation(object sender, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        Log("SYS", "I", sender, format, args);  
    }

    public static void LogSystemWarning(object sender, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        Log("SYS", "W", sender, format, args);  
    }

    public static void LogSystemError(object sender, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        Log("SYS", "E", sender, format, args);  
    }

    public static void LogRaw(object sender, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        Log("RAW", string.Empty, sender, format, args);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (null != _lock)
        {
            _lock.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Most times I just log as such: GlobalLogger.LogApplicationInformation(this, "Info message: {0}", randomTypeArg);

Comment: You are using a singleton pattern and I understand that, but a singleton only works if you are running in the same virtual machine.  Two different applications, even if they use the same GlobalLogger class, will have different instances of the singleton and will have two different locks.  Thus, they will still get contention problems, I think.  I do like the design of what you did and may alter what I have to go with that.  Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. Lemme think, dont have anything off the top of my head